# Wait till function completes and return Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscribe

How can i make the `subscribe` wait till my logic completes and `transform` returns the updated `keys` object ?

```
transform(value: any, args:string) : any {
    let keys = [];

    this.http.get('src/app/enum-data/enum.json').subscribe(data => {

      this.List = data;
      // Logic here (data vs value)
      for (var enumMember in value) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(enumMember, 10))) {
          keys.push({key: enumMember, value: value[enumMember]});
        } 
      }
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    return keys;

  }
```

HTML:

```
  <select>
          <option *ngFor="let item of gendersEnum | keys: 'gender'" [value]="item.key">{{item.value}}</option>
  </select>
```

This is a `pipe` module. Tried returning `keys` within the `subscribe` but still the same issue.

Comment: What does pipe *module* refer to in this context? Are you writing your own Angular pipe? https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't subscribe your Observable here. Just map the response with RxJs operators and subscribe when calling `transform(...)`.

```
transform(value: any, args: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('src/app/enum-data/enum.json').pipe(
            map(data => {
                let keys = [];
                // Logic here (data vs value)
                for (const enumMember in value) {
                    if (!isNaN(parseInt(enumMember, 10))) {
                        keys.push({key: enumMember, value: value[enumMember]});
                    }
                }
                return keys;
            })
        );
    }
```

A better approach is to use `async` pipe to let angular subscribe and unsubscribe your observable :

```
 <select>
          <option *ngFor="let item of gendersEnum | keys: 'gender' | async" [value]="item.key">{{item.value}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: updated the question where i'm using the pipe, how can i use the async pipe? just by adding `async` in the html?

Comment: In your component typescript you need to assign your observable to the class (with `this`) then in your template `#ngFor="let item of (yourObservable | async)"`

Comment: You can learn more here : https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794

Comment: It gets me `InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'` when tried to use the async pipe like this, `*ngFor="let item of (gendersEnum |  async) | keys: 'gender'"`

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in method.

````
transform(value: any, args:string) : Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get('src/app/enum-data/enum.json').map(data => {
     let keys = [];
      this.List = data;
      // Logic here (data vs value)
      for (var enumMember in value) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(enumMember, 10))) {
          keys.push({key: enumMember, value: value[enumMember]});
        } 
      }
      return keys;
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  }```
Now you can subscribe Your translation method.
````